# How to remove corner radius from button used in List?

Tags: swiftui, visionos

Here the button which does not fit into List when hovered.

```swift
Section(header: Text("Schema Items")) {
    ForEach(cards[cardIndex].indentedSchemaItems.indices, id: \.self) { index in
        Button(action: {
           
        }) {
            HStack {
               
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 8)
            .frame(height: 88)
            .cornerRadius(1)
        }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) // Remove button style to make it look like a regular view
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .frame(height: 88)
        .cornerRadius(1)
    }
}.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 0)
```

look corners:

[image]

Comment: don't forget to mention you are targetting `Vison Pro`, to help the contributors.

Comment: You have 5 open curly brackets as opposed to 6 curly brackets.  How does that work?

Comment: removed one just now

Comment: Have you tried `.contentShape(..., .hoverEffect)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the content shape for specifically hover effect using something like the following:

```swift
     YourView() 
       .contentShape(.hoverEffect, RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4))
```

In your case, it can be used like this:

```
 Button(action: {
           
        }) {
            HStack {
               
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 8)
            .frame(height: 88)
            .cornerRadius(1)
        }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        .contentShape(.hoverEffect, Rectangle())
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .frame(height: 88)
        .cornerRadius(1)
```

Comment: I tried both `.contentShape(.hoverEffect, Rectangle())` and `.contentShape(.hoverEffect, RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 1))` or other small cornerRadius value, but none will fill ups all space in cell at highlighting.